Ubuntu freezes when i typed in the correct password
I use lubuntu 22.04, about 2 days ago i install some games on my laptop and everything seems fine for a couple of hours until my laptop start to lag very hard. I REISUB it and reboot the laptop. When I’m typed the correct password, my laptop freezes but my mouse can still move around. I REISUB it again and the issue is still occuring. I checked the disk using recovery mode and it saids drive /home is 100% used. So how can I fix it and grow my drive
My laptop: Dell vostro 3450, 2GB of RAM, 116GB HDD, 19.8GB used for /home

You need sufficient space in $HOME for a GUI login to proceed, from your description it sounds like you lack sufficient space and thus a GUI login cannot continue, but if you switch to a text terminal (eg. Ctrl+Alt+F4) and login there, you should be able to confirm & create space.

I can do switch to a terminal using that command, in $HOME theres a little bit of space there. Can you show me how to confirm and create space in terminal?

You need to rm or delete files, as to what files you need, I can't help you. I'm unsure what space you'll require to login, you may need 450-600MB free or more, but I'd aim for close to 1GB of space being kept available as working files are created/removed as required.

How do i see files name using terminal, im not sure which files i want to delete

I'd use something like ls -ltrhS to list files (sorted by Size with largest last) as its space you need to create; but its up to you. If you're used to using a GUI only (ie. not terminal) then boot a live system as @Alain Reve suggests; navigate to your installed system and use GUI tools to explore directories.

I have another question, how can i grow my /home disk using terminal?

What partition should i increase on terminal in order for my laptop to run

Take a bootable usb stick and boot from it. Then you can select "Try Ubuntu" and look on your hard disk for some large files to delete. You would have to use another computer to create this bootable usb stick if you don't already have one.

Can i boot using a hard drive with ubuntu in that drive. I don’t have a usb and another computer

If the hard drive comes from the same computer, you can try.

Can you show me how? Im new to ubuntu
